# Is there a tool to strip off code under switches defined?

Tags: c++, c

I have a chunk of C and C++ code. I have to release the source to two different customers. I don't want them to see what the features others having. So, I'm planning to use switches for compilation. When to deliver the code, I would like to have few lines of the code stripped out. I know I can write a script to do it but I would like to know if are there any tools that exist to do this job.

```
#ifdef CUSTOMER_1
Code for Customer 1
#else //Customer_2
Code for Customer 2
#endif
```

For customer 2, I would like to have the code removed which comes under `#ifdef` and `#else`. I would like to remove the line `#endif`. Are there any tools that are readily available for this?

Comment: Yes, more than one. Google "partial c preprocessor".

Comment: That's what exactly I was looking for. Let me try that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a utility called `unifdef` that's designed exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you put the customer-specific bits in a a *customers.h* file and include that file? You give different customers different *customers.h*. You haven't fully explained the problem, but by first sniff, static filtering of source code is a kludge.

Comment: I like this solution because it will make your customers feel special.

Comment: If they feel special, you've done it wrong. They shouldn't know that you're doing it. If they realize they are a special case, they'll also realize that there are other special cases, and that they aren't special because there are other customers just like them. :)

Answer (score 0):

The C preprocessor can do this for you of course, but it will process any other directives too. I think you would be best to do this with a specialised script